# AngularJS and PHP login

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, pdo

I am trying to create a simple application using angularjs, php and mysql..

I do have a login page which uses angularjs, PDO and mysql.

however I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or the other way around..

is it okay to still use `$_SESSION` to verify user login. or should I use angularjs authentication? I'm still new to angularjs so I don't know if there's a similar code to `$_SESSION` in angularjs.

I just need your advice guys.

thanks in advance.

here's my code.

**HTML Login**

```
include "lib/connection.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == '1'){  
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Implementing AngularJS</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div class="login col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <h2>Please Log in</h2>
        <form>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="users.username"  />
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="users.password"  />
        <input type="submit" name="cmd_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="login()" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="message">
            <p>Invalid Username or Password!</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</body> 

</html>
```

**ANGULARJS CODE**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$window','$scope', '$http', function($window, $scope, $http) {


$scope.login = function(){
    console.log($scope.users);
    var inputs = 'myData=' + JSON.stringify($scope.users);
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'lib/login_c.php',
        data: inputs,
        headers:{'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function(res){
        console.log(res);
        if(res == 1){
             $window.location.href = "index.php";
        }else{
            $scope.message = true;
        }
    });
};

}]);
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

include "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['myData'])){

$login_obj = json_decode($_POST['myData']);
if(!empty($login_obj->username) AND !empty($login_obj->password)){

    $instantiate_login_c = new login_c;

    $condition = "username = :username AND password = :password";
    $arr = array('username' => $login_obj->username, 'password' => $login_obj->password);

    $result = $instantiate_login_c->getWhere('users', $condition, $arr);

    if($result){
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = '1';
        echo 1;
    }else{ 
        echo 0;}


}else{
    echo 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Is it okay for me to still use the `$_SESSION`? I really need advice guys.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is okay, you can do it both ways, but doing it the angular way is certainly the best route to go.

Comment: what do you mean sir?.. so, it is okay if I do my authentication like that?.. what is the difference between angular authentication and mine, mine is like an ajax type? is there a downside on my authentication than angular authentication?

Comment: What i meant to say was both is correct so when you do AUTH for Angular web applications you will do this in your App.js in the .run section, when your app runs for the first time it will do a http request to the php which will then check if the session exists and return true... in your routes you can say access: true or false stating that access is needed or not when going to a page directly. Hope this helps.